# Need suggestion in optimizing the below code

Tags: java

I need some guidance as how can I optimize the below code. As one can see , i am creating a new object everytime to set each value. How can I do it in a better way

```
Balance[] balance = new Balance[3];
CurAmt curAmt = new CurAmt();
Balance bal = new Balance();
bal.setBalType("currentBalance");
curAmt.setCurCode(entry.getValue().get(0).getAs("CURRENT_BALANCE_CURRENCY_CODE"));
curAmt.setContent(entry.getValue().get(0).getAs("CURRENT_BALANCE"));
bal.setCurAmt(curAmt);
balance[0] = bal;

CurAmt curAmt1 = new CurAmt();
Balance bal1 = new Balance();
bal1.setBalType("availableBalance");
curAmt1.setCurCode(entry.getValue().get(0).getAs("AVAILABLE_BALANCE_CURRENCY_CODE"));
curAmt1.setContent(entry.getValue().get(0).getAs("AVAILABLE_BALANCE"));
bal1.setCurAmt(curAmt1);
balance[1] = bal1;

CurAmt curAmt2 = new CurAmt();
Balance bal2 = new Balance();
bal2.setBalType("interestEarnedYtd");
curAmt2.setCurCode(entry.getValue().get(0).getAs("YTD_CURRENCY_CODE"));
curAmt2.setContent(entry.getValue().get(0).getAs("TD_AMOUNT"));
bal2.setCurAmt(curAmt2);
balance[2] = bal2;

Obj.setBalance(balance);
```

Comment: why do you want to change it? First thing could be constructor parameters instead of setter calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about code performance, I can only see one optimization.  You evaluate this 6 times, and the JIT compiler probably can't optimize it:

```
entry.getValue().get(0)
```

Do it once and assign the value to a temporary variable.  (It is unclear if this will make a significant difference.  And you were just doing this for performance reasons, you would be advised to **profile** your application first.  There is no point in optimizing application code that is not a performance hotspot.)

If you are talking about *programmer* efficiency (i.e. code readability) I can see a block of code that is repeated 3 times with different parameters.  You can turn it into a method; e.g.

```
private Balance createBalance(Value v, String type, String currency, String balance) {
    CurAmt curAmt = new CurAmt();
    Balance bal = new Balance();
    bal.setBalType(type);
    curAmt.setCurCode(value.getAs(currency));
    curAmt.setContent(value.getAs(ballance));
    bal.setCurAmt(curAmt);
    return bal;
}
```

then call it with the appropriate parameters.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen.. Can you clarify what is the `Value` type class here?

Comment: It denotes the type of whatever `entry.getValue().get(int)` returns.  Change it as required.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen for your help